# How can I get Mac OS X's proxy information in a Bash script?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, proxy

I have several network locations set up on my laptop: Work, Home, etc. The work one(s) all have a proxy server set up, while the others don't. This works fine for OSX applications -- Safari, Mail, even Firefox and Thunderbird with the [System Proxy](http://systemproxy.mozdev.org/) plugin.

For terminal applications such as `git`, `svn`, `gem`, and `curl` I have the following in my `.bash_profile`:

```
export HTTP_PROXY='http://proxy.mycompany.com:80'
export http_proxy=$HTTP_PROXY
```

My question is this: is there some way to make the exported variable look up the value from my system's current location? I'd prefer it to be done dynamically (so if I change locations during a terminal session it will change), but I'd be happy with just one that set it when `.bash_profile` ran (meaning I'd have to start a new terminal session when I changed locations).

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a bash script which uses networksetup and security to extract the proxy information and set http_proxy and https_proxy:
https://gist.github.com/alexargo/4657760

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work, but I'm not sure how robust it is:

```
system_profiler SPNetworkDataType|grep "HTTP Proxy Server"|awk {'sub(/^.*:[ \t]*/, "", $0); print $0;'}
```

It doesn't work if your Location uses a `proxy.pac` instead of a hard-coded proxy location.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to include the port number.

Answer (score 10):

What version of Mac OS X? I'm not positive the tool is included with Mac OS X 10.4 or earlier.

`networksetup` should be what you're looking for, namely `sudo networksetup -getwebproxy NAME_OF_NETWORK_DEVICE` (eg. sudo networksetup -getwebproxy Airport)

The output comes out as so:

```
Enabled: Yes
Server: SERVER_ADDRESS
Port: 123
Authenticated Proxy Enabled: 0 for false, 1 for true
```

So you will need to convert the output to something usable.

A really crude example using awk a couple times (my awk skills are rather basic) would be:

```
sudo networksetup -getwebproxy Airport | awk {'print $2'} | awk {'getline l2; getline l3; print "http://"l2":"l3'} | head -n 1
```

Results in an output `http://SERVER_ADDRESS:123`

Comment: A list of all services: `networksetup -listallnetworkservices`

Comment: I love the idea, but it doesn't work for me. If I just do `sudo networksetup -getwebproxy Ethernet`, I get the printout and then a segfault. I imagine the segfault causes the pipe to break, so `awk` never gets anything to parse.

Comment: Is there any information output? And does it still segfault without the awk commands?

Comment: I think I actually saw that segmentation fault on my own Macs once. I don't have the issue on 10.5.8 or 10.6.1 now (both Intel). Maybe you're on some other version?

Comment: I'm on 10.5.8, and it happens without the `awk`. Adding the awk makes the segfault message disappear . . . along with all other output.

Comment: @Gaius: Then the networksetup command is borked for some reason. Does running `networksetup -listallnetworkservices` segfault as well?

Comment: @Chaelion: nope, that works just fine.

Comment: If it's been long since you changed the proxy settings: maybe make some dummy edits and save, and then see if that fixes the segmentation fault? If it was indeed one of my own Macs that gave that error, then it must have been my MacBook, on which I surely did not explicitly do anything to solve it. I did install all updates, and upgraded to 10.6.1. I also recently changed the value for "Bypass proxy settings for these Hosts and Domains". Maybe I had the OpenDNS DNS servers set up at that time (though that's not part of the output of `networksetup -getwebproxy`)...

Comment: I tried making changes to both the proxy server and to the bypass settings. Neither helped.

Answer (score 9):

Additionally this command may help to discover other proxy settings : `scutil --proxy`

Comment: This was the only command that returned a proxy (`networksetup` nor `system_profiler` displayed it) - and that was the one being used by Safari/Firefox. This was when I was using the in-built VPN.

Answer (score 6):

In the [answer above](https://superuser.com/a/98976/24010), there is a [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/48480/how-can-i-get-mac-os-xs-proxy-information-in-a-bash-script#comment287602_98976) from [tlrobinson](https://superuser.com/users/78682/tlrobinson) about how it doesn't include the port number.

You can do that by switching out **HTTP Proxy Server** with **HTTP Proxy Port**

I have also seen this done like this:

```
system_profiler SPNetworkDataType | grep "HTTP Proxy Server" | awk '{print $4}' | head -1
system_profiler SPNetworkDataType | grep "HTTP Proxy Port" | awk '{print $4}' | head -1
```

Answer (score 1):

I just did this `scutil --proxy` and copied the `HTTPPort` parameters and the `HTTPProxy` parameters.
Then I did this `export ALL_PROXY=HTTPPort:HTTPProxy` where you will replace the `HTTPPort` and `HTTPProxy` with your parameters.
Then finally, I did this `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"`
Now you're good to go.

Comment: Basically to make it simpler.. do this 'ALL_PROXY=127.0.0.1:9001' and then try installing brew again. Now it will work insha'allah

Comment: You can edit your own posts to improve them or add information you feel they need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [little tool](https://github.com/janvogt/export-proxies) I wrote, that sets the commonly used environment variables for proxies. Usage is straightforward:

1. Compile it with xCode.
2. Add:

   ```
   eval `./path/to/export-proxies`
   ```

   to your `.profile`, `.bashrc`, or `.bash_profile`.

After that you can use variables like `$HTTP_PROXY`, `$http_proxy`, `$HttpProxy`, etc. for all protocols (HTTP, FTP, SOCKS) including the `$NO_PROXY` exceptions. This will work for most CLI tool and gets the settings from the OS X control panel.